# Do Shell Script Issue in Applescript

Tags: shell, audio, applescript

This script is to rename WAV files to AIF and add a 2 second silence at the end of each file, then delete the WAV files and move all the content to the root directory and delete the empty folders.

The problem is via Applescripts the "do shell script" line does not execute.

```
do shell script "find " & rootDirectory & " -name \\*.wav -exec sox {} {}.aif pad 0 2 \\;"
```

If I run it as a "do script" it's fine.

**The script:**

```
tell application "Finder" to set rootDirectory to (target of Finder window 1) as string
set rootDirectory to quoted form of POSIX path of rootDirectory

do shell script "find " & rootDirectory & " -name \\*.wav -exec sox {} {}.aif pad 0 2 \\;" -- change to AIF and add 2 second silence 
delay 10
do shell script "find " & rootDirectory & " -name \\*.wav -exec rm {} \\;" -- delete WAV files
delay 5
do shell script "find " & rootDirectory & " -type f -exec mv {} " & rootDirectory & " \\;" --Move all files into rootDirectory
do shell script "find " & rootDirectory & " -depth -type d -exec rmdir {} " & " \\;" -- Remove all subdirectories of XMoveTo Root.app:
```

**The "Do Script" workaround:**

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "find " & rootDirectory & " -name \\*.wav -exec sox {} {}.aif pad 0 2 \\;" in front window
    delay 10
    do script "find " & rootDirectory & " -name \\*.wav -exec rm {} \\;" in front window
end tell
```

Ideally it would be great if it all ran via "do shell script."
Also any idea how I can loose the .wav when renaming to .aif? The files are coming out like this; newfile.wav.aif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `sox` on the path? I can't think of any other reason why the `find` command would not work.

You might write the script as a shell script instead:

```
set -e
dir=$(osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to POSIX path of (target of Finder window 1 as alias)')
find "$dir" -type f  | while read f; do
  if [[ $f = *.wav ]]; then
    sox "$f" "$dir$(basename "$f" .wav).aif" pad 0 2
    rm "$f"
  else
    mv "$f" "$dir"
  fi
done
rm -r "$dir"/*/
```

Comment: Thanks you where right I needed to define SoX. Will most definitely look into shell scripting.